# Unity c# having trouble getting it too detect when a key is not pressed

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, if-statement, input, c#-4.0

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("z") == true)
        {
            moveSpeed = 10;
            
            
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("z") == false)
        {
            moveSpeed = 5;
        }
```

that is the code.

When it runs it seems to detect that z is pressed and than set moveSpeed to 10. But than it fails to detect that z is not pressed and resets moveSpeed back to 5.

I have tried a few variations of this code, all seem to have the same result.

Comment: try `if (Input.GetKey("z")) { moveSpeed = 10; } else { moveSpeed = 5; }`

Comment: In this case I would actually prefer @Ruzihm 's way over the accepted answer

Comment: @derHugo that method didn't work, I had already tried it.

Comment: Tbh I doubt that .. it basically does the same ;) I would even have made it `moveSpeed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z) ? 10 : 5;` actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use Input.GetKeyUp("z")